# What is the difference betwen --export-dynamic and --export-all-symbols?

Tags: cygwin, ld, linker-flags

After compiling on Cygwin with gcc or clang, ld complains about

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: --export-dynamic is not supported for PE+ targets, did you mean --export-all-symbols?
```

Changing the linkerflag as suggested fixes this behavior, but I am not sure if this is correct. Therefore the question is simple:

What is the difference betwen `--export-dynamic` and `--export-all-symbols`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`--export-dynamic`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-_002dE) is for ELF targets:

> Note that this option is specific to ELF targeted ports. PE targets support a similar function to export all symbols from a DLL or EXE; see the description of ‘`--export-all-symbols`’ below.

[`--export-all-symbols`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#index-_002d_002dexport_002dall_002dsymbols) is for PE targets:

> This option is specific to the i386 PE targeted port of the linker

It would probably have been possible to subsume both under `--export-dynamic` (because that was there first), but the implementation is completely different, and this leaked out to the `ld` command line interface.